# print output only if real boolean is passed to the function

Tags: javascript, boolean

What is an **elegant way** for debug function to print only if the value passed is an actual boolean value. If an object or string is passed as the second parameter, it should NOT print the output message. If I can avoid comparison of real boolean within the debug function, it would be an elegant solution to me.

```
function debug(msg, enable) {
       this.msg = msg;
       if (Boolean(enable))
         console.log(this.msg);
}
```

`debug("message", true) //should output message`
`debug("message", "random")// should not output the console message.`

Comment: `console.log(typeof true); // expected output: "boolean"` as seen on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the question whether you want to output the message if `enable` is a boolean (whether it's `true` or `false`) *(the way I originally read it)* or only if it's `true` (*the way I read it the second time)*.

#### If only for booleans (whether `true` or `false`)

If for either `true` or `false`, then:

```
if (typeof enable === "boolean")
    console.log(this.msg);
```

or

```
if (enable === true || enable === false)
    console.log(this.msg);
```

or (but I think you said you didn't like this one):

```
if (Boolean(enable) === enable)
    console.log(this.msg);
```

Live Example:

```js
function debug(msg, enable) {
       this.msg = msg;
       if (enable === true)
         console.log(this.msg);
}

debug("one", true);      // prints
debug("two", "random");  // doesn't, it's not boolean, even though "random" is truthy
```

#### If only for `true`

If you want to print the message only for `true`, then just use strict equality, since you want `false` to also not print the message:

```
if (enable === true)
    console.log(this.msg);
```

With `===`, the expression will be false if:

- `enable` isn't a boolean (because `===` requires the operand types to match), or
- `enable` is `false` (because although the types match, the values don't)

Live Example:

```js
function debug(msg, enable) {
       this.msg = msg;
       if (enable === true)
         console.log(this.msg);
}

debug("one", true);       // prints
debug("two", false);      // doesn't, it's false
debug("three", "random"); // doesn't, it's not boolean, even though "random" is truthy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check typeof enable

```js
function debug(msg, enable) {
    this.msg = msg;
    if (typeof enable === 'boolean')
      console.log(this.msg);
}

debug("message", true) //should output message
debug("message", "random")
```

If you wish to show message only when enable is boolean and truthy than you can extend above code

```
if (typeof enable === 'boolean' && enable)
```

```js
function debug(msg, enable) {
    this.msg = msg;
    if (typeof enable === 'boolean' && enable)
      console.log(this.msg);
}

debug("message", true) //should output message
debug("message", "random")
debug("message", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `===`.

```
function debug(msg, enable) {
    this.msg = msg;
    if (enable === true)
        console.log(this.msg);
}
```